# Travel Badge Ranking List

Tags: discussion, fun, badges

In a fun attempt to try to add some competition other than just rep, let's look at the number of [badges earned on the site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

I'll list some of the higher ones, but feel free to add / update rankings - I'll make it an editable answer.

Hopefully it'll also encourage people to try for some of the rarer badges on the site!

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/181665/badge-counts-by-user. Unfortunately, it seems that it is not functioning correctly. It doesn't give the correct result for Gold, Silver and Bronze, only for the total number of badges.

Comment: @wythagoras Rather than check specific badge IDs [we can check badge class](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/746616/badge-counts-by-user), as I now see Glorfindel did.

Answer (score 11):

This [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/1105200/travel-badge-ranking-list) will produce the complete ranking list (yay! I'm 221st!), with the caveat that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning. You can [download the CSV results](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/csv/911615) or [fork the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/fork/733370) to do some analysis yourself.

To facilitate updating the list, I've created [another version](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/748113/travel-badge-ranking-list-v2) for which the [CSV results](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/csv/928754) can be **copy-pasted directly into the list**.

Answer (score 10):

```
+------+--------------------+------+--------+--------+
| Rank |    User            | Gold | Silver | Bronze |
+------+--------------------+------+--------+--------+
|    1 | Mark Mayo          |   81 |   589  |  1324  |
|    2 | hippietrail        |   47 |   228  |   565  |
|    3 | JonathanReez       |   45 |   263  |   542  |
|    4 | RoflcoptrException |   45 |   171  |   389  |
|    5 | Gagravarr          |   43 |   200  |   413  |
|    6 | Nean Der Thal      |   28 |   269  |   370  |
|    7 | nsn                |   25 |   101  |   219  |
|    8 | Gayot Fow          |   24 |   207  |   392  |
|    9 | jpatokal           |   19 |   406  |   565  |
|   10 | Blaszard           |   16 |    53  |   112  |
|   11 | jrdioko            |   16 |    41  |    85  |    
|   12 | Ankur Banerjee     |   15 |   126  |   234  |
|   13 | phoog              |   14 |   198  |   283  |
|   14 | JoErNanO           |   14 |   145  |   242  |
|   15 | VMAtm              |   14 |    81  |   128  |
|   16 | Dirty-flow         |   14 |    59  |   116  |
|   17 | Crazydre           |   13 |   109  |   255  |    
|   18 | Willeke            |   13 |    96  |   196  |
|   19 | Flimzy             |   13 |    78  |   150  |  
|   20 | Ivan               |   13 |    67  |   149  | 
|   21 | Jonik              |   13 |    56  |   105  |
|   22 | Zach Lipton        |   12 |   207  |   270  |
|   23 | gerrit             |   12 |   105  |   235  |    
|   24 | Kate Gregory       |   11 |   174  |   268  |
|   25 | mts                |   11 |   113  |   212  |  
+------+--------------------+------+--------+--------+
```

Ranked by number of Gold badges, then number of Silver badges, then number of Bronze badges.